# Control GPIO of Rasberry PI using chaincode - Hyperledger Fabric V1.0

Tags: iot, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, gpio

I'm trying to control LED using rpi that is a peer in hyperledger fabric network. My network (PC and RPI) is as follow:

- A Certificate Authority (CA) — PC1
- An Orderer — PC1
- 1 PEER (peer0) on — PC1
- 1 PEER (peer1) on — RP
- CLI on —  RPI

I setup the above network successfully, and i'm able to run the chaincode example 2 that is provided by hyperledger fabric (install, query,invoke). 
i have developed my own chaincode that can be used to turn on and off a LED connected to the rpi from the blockchain. The problem is that i'm getting the below error (Timeout):

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   timeout expired while starting chaincode mychaincode:1.0

This is my chaincode:

```
    package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "os"
    "github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio" //To Map GPIO of RPI
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)
var (
        pin = rpio.Pin(3)
)

// SimpleChaincode example simple Chaincode implementation
type SimpleChaincode struct {


}
func (t *SimpleChaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("LED ON")
    _, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    var A string    // Entities
    var Aval int // Asset holdings
    var err error

    if len(args) != 2 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2")
    }
    if err := rpio.Open(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
     }
    A = args[0]
    Aval, err = strconv.Atoi(args[1])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Expecting integer value for asset holding")
    }

    fmt.Printf("Aval = %d", Aval)
    if Aval == 1{
     pin.High() //turn on
    } else {
     pin.Low() //turn off
    }
    // Write the state to the ledger
    err = stub.PutState(A, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }


    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (t *SimpleChaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("ex02 Invoke")
    function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    if function == "invoke" {
        // Make payment of X units from A to B
        return t.invoke(stub, args)
    } else if function == "delete" {
        // Deletes an entity from its state
        return t.delete(stub, args)
    } else if function == "query" {
        // the old "Query" is now implemtned in invoke
        return t.query(stub, args)
    }

    return shim.Error("Invalid invoke function name. Expecting \"invoke\" \"delete\" \"query\"")
}

// Transaction makes payment of X units from A to B
func (t *SimpleChaincode) invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    var A string    // Entities
    var Aval int // Asset holdings
    var X int          // Transaction value
    var err error

    if len(args) != 2 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2")
    }

    A = args[0]

    // Get the state from the ledger
    // TODO: will be nice to have a GetAllState call to ledger
    Avalbytes, err := stub.GetState(A)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to get state")
    }
    if Avalbytes == nil {
        return shim.Error("Entity not found")
    }
    Aval, _ = strconv.Atoi(string(Avalbytes))


    // Perform the execution
    X, err = strconv.Atoi(args[1])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Invalid transaction amount, expecting a integer value")
    }
    Aval = X
    fmt.Printf("Aval = %d", Aval)
    if Aval == 1{
     pin.High()
    } else {
     pin.Low()
    }
    // Write the state back to the ledger
    err = stub.PutState(A, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }
    return shim.Success(nil)
}
// Deletes an entity from state
func (t *SimpleChaincode) delete(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    if len(args) != 1 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1")
    }

    A := args[0]

    // Delete the key from the state in ledger
    err := stub.DelState(A)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to delete state")
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// query callback representing the query of a chaincode
func (t *SimpleChaincode) query(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    var A string // Entities
    var err error

    if len(args) != 1 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting name of the person to query")
    }

    A = args[0]

    // Get the state from the ledger
    Avalbytes, err := stub.GetState(A)
    if err != nil {
        jsonResp := "{\"Error\":\"Failed to get state for " + A + "\"}"
        return shim.Error(jsonResp)
    }

    if Avalbytes == nil {
        jsonResp := "{\"Error\":\"Nil amount for " + A + "\"}"
        return shim.Error(jsonResp)
    }

    jsonResp := "{\"Name\":\"" + A + "\",\"Amount\":\"" + string(Avalbytes) + "\"}"
    fmt.Printf("Query Response:%s\n", jsonResp)
    return shim.Success(Avalbytes)
}

func main() {
    err := shim.Start(new(SimpleChaincode))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting Simple chaincode: %s", err)
    }
}
```

How can i solve this issue as there is no syntax errors at all ?

Comment: Did you vendor "github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio" with your chaincode?

Comment: I have import the "github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio" on my Chaincode, and also before installing the Chaincode I have run the following command: go get github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio

Comment: You actually need to "vendor" the go-rpio package ... you can use a tool like "govendor" to accomplish this

Comment: Please paste the log. In which step you get this error, chain code instantiate?